# Need to check the Value should not be Null or 0 from whole Array list using Groovy script Assertion

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am working API which give the list of Ride booking and from the Json response i need to check the DestinationEstimatedTravelTime  should not be 0 or Null

Expected via script Assertion: it should scan all the available Array Response and check condition that the "DestinationETA" should be greater then 0.

Below is the image of my Response

[image]

Below is the code that i have used I have used For loop.

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
//grab response
def response = messageExchange.response.responseContent
def jsosl = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response)
for(int i =0 ; i < jsos1.size(); i++)
{
    if(Results[i].DestinationETA == 0 | Results[i].DestinationETA != "Null" )
    {
        log.info("Values are greater than 0")
    }
    else
    {
        log.info("test case Fail  ")
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your error is because you call it `jsosl` in one place, then `jsos1` in the next

(last character is a lowercase L then a 1)

You could change your code to:

```
assert json.Results.every { it.DestinationETA }
```

As in groovy, `0` or `null` is `false`

Comment: i request you to please write full code if possible as i have changed my name to Jsos and replaced it but its not working also i have  used your code that you have mention i am getting  " No Such Property: DestinationETA for class: java.util.TreeMap$Entry" error message

Comment: Fixed. It was hard to tell from a screenshot what the format of the json was

Answer (score 0):

I was working on this and I my self found the solution

```
    //Import file
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import com.eviware.soapui.model.testsuite.TestRunner.*
import com.eviware.soapui.model.testsuite.*
import com.eviware.soapui.model.*
//Grab Response
def response = messageExchange.response.responseContent
def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(response)
//take count 
def count = json.Results.size()
for(int i=0; i<count; i++) //loop to traverse to each object 
{
log.info(json.Results[i].DestinationETA) // print result 
assert json.Results[i].DestinationETA != null
assert json.Results[i].DestinationETA != 0 
}
```